# How to implement my own formula in pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matrix

I am working with the diamonds dataset. I am working with two columns from this in particular: carat and table.

I must create a function that takes the dataframe and computes the distance based on the following formula:

```
Python

$distance = ((carat_i - carat_j)/0.8)^2 + ((table_i - table_j)/57)^2
```

The function should output a matrix, in which the ith row and jth column of the matrix should be the distance between the ith and jth measurements.

I have imported the dataframes as two columns successfully as demonstrated by the code below.

```
# where df is diamonds
def exercise3(df):
    df1 = DataFrame(df)
    df2 = Dataframe(df1,
        columns=['carat','table'])
```

But i am unsure how to implement my formula to take the next step

Comment: Could you show us the structure of each dataframe ? with appropriate column names.

Comment: I agree a print out of df1.head(3) and df2.head(3) would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this with sample data and this should work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
data = [[5, 10], [7, 15], [10, 14]]

test_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['carat', 'table'])

def exercise3(df):
    output_array = numpy.zeros(shape=(len(df),len(df)))
    for index_i, row_i in df.iterrows():
        for index_j, row_j in df.iterrows():
            output_array[index_i,index_j] = ((row_i['carat'] - row_j['carat'])/0.8)**2 + ((row_i['table'] - row_j['table'])/57)**2
    return output_array

test = exercise3(test_df)
print(test)
```